# Embedded video in WinForms (AxShockwaveFlash)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, flash, embedded-resource, movie

I have uploaded a couple of tutorial videos in youtube.

In my winforms application (by using the AxShockwaveFlash object) i reproduce the selected video by the user.

AxShockwaveFlash1.LoadMovie(http://www.youtube ..video1)

Here comes the story.

The first time the user selects a video, reproduction works like a charm.

When the user selects to see the second video
AxShockwaveFlash1.LoadMovie(http://www.youtube ..video2)

the ShockwaveFlash continues the reproduction of the first selection

Answer (score 2):

Try to use

```
AxShockwaveFlash1.Stop();
AxShockwaveFlash1.Movie = "Your source";
AxShockwaveFlash1.Play();
```

Pattern to avoid leaving flash arguments behind.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing how you have integrated the video in your form, the method I would do is using a webBrowsercontrol in the form and embed the video in the control.
[msdn on webBrowsercontrol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I had encountered this problem and resolved it by changing the Embed property of the Ax object control to False.

I embed the videos via the movie URL each time as follows:

http://www.youtube.com/v/targetmovie&feature=player_embedded

Works a treat

Answer (score 0):

Tamir,
the video is embedded. Not stored locally

Comment: Movie property is only link, like as for LoadMoview

Answer (score 0):

This is because your application is loading flash player loader from the cache and then it's loading the real player from the site , finally this yield a security exception.
In internet explorer , in internet options set to check for new versions of the documents each time you visit the page.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to extract the FLV file like here:

[Getting an FLV from YouTube in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883737/getting-an-flv-from-youtube-in-net)