# How to embed Flv Player embeded in C# windows form application?

Tags: c#, youtube, flv, jwplayer

Can i use or embed any of FLV players like JW player in C# Windows Form Application without using web browser ? And if yes how to use it for playing Flv video or to play Youtube video ?

Comment: I'm a little confused when you say that you don't want to use a web browser. The FLV player usually is displayed in a web browser.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Embedding flv (flash) player in windows forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43533/embedding-flv-flash-player-in-windows-forms)

Comment: @quakkels You can make use of FLV players on the Desktop....http://www.wimpyplayer.com/products/wimpy_standalone_flv_player.html

Comment: @Aaron - Yes. I understand that. That's why I said 'usually'. It sounds like he's talking about a website, but I'm not sure from his question. I was asking for clarification.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Embedded video in WinForms (AxShockwaveFlash)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/482697/embedded-video-in-winforms-axshockwaveflash)